# M6E Nano stops reading after 5 seconds

Tags: rfid, reader, usbserial, nano

I have a M6E Nano connected with a Serial Basic USB breakout board.
Connecting everything together and using the Universal Reader Assistant works, but when I start reading tags nothing shows and the board disconnects after a few seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Because the board is not getting enough power it will brown out. Resetting the board.

`Make sure the USB breakout board is supplying 5V of power instead of the default 3.3V.`

On the back of the board is a 3 pad jumper that you need to sever and re-solder to 5V.